# Spark - Add Worker from Local Machine (standalone spark cluster manager)?

Tags: parallel-processing, apache-spark

When running spark 1.4.0 in a single machine, I can add worker by using this command "./bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker myhostname:7077". The official documentation points out another way by adding "myhostname:7077" to the "conf/slaves" file followed by executing the command "sbin/start-all.sh" which invoke the master and all workers listed in conf/slaves file. However, the later method doesn't work for me (with time-out error). Can anyone help me with this?

Here is my conf/slaves file (assume the master URL is myhostname:700):

myhostname:700

Answer (score 0):

The conf.slaves file should just be the list of the hostnames, you don't need to include the port # that spark runs on (I think if you do it will try and ssh on that port which is probably where the timeout comes from).

Comment: Thanks, Holden. However it still doesn't work after I remove the port. Here is the entire name "Tsung-Weis-MacBook-Pro.local" I added in slaves file and I am getting Connection refused error.

Comment: Can you post the command and logs? Also what happens when you ssh to that host?

Comment: If your getting connection refused error my _guess_ would be that you don't have an ssh server installed so I'd install an ssh server and make sure to set up passwordless (e.g. ssh key) based access.

Comment: Thank you Holden. I finally got it solved. I forgot to turn on the remove access for my local host. Now it works :) appreciate your help!